# Weird PHP session

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I've got a perfectly functioning site which uses sessions. The only exception, is one particular page. The page performs some DB SELECTS, verification stuff, etc. etc.
Then, later on, in the HTML part, ive got a  tag. Between that, ive got

```
<?php
    $classes = explode(",", $_SESSION['classes']);
    foreach ($classes as $class) {
        echo "<option>".$class."</option>";
    }
?>
```

Now $_SESSION['classes'] is a comma separated string. Example: "10 A,11 D,12 C"
here's the weird part, when i load this page, everything works perfectly, and i get a drop-down select with options 10 A, 11 D and 12 C... but, when i refresh the page, I get a dropdown box with only one option: `Array`

Yes, it just says Array.... no other options.

And no, i haven't set the value to anything else after that PHP block. in fact, i dont have another PHP block after this one

To debug it, I added a php block with the code: `echo $_SESSION['classes'];` after the `</select>` tag, and the first page load, it said `10 A,11 D,12 C`. After refresh, it said `Array`

Then i tried `var_dump($_SESSION);` and it said `["classes"]=> &string(9) "11 A,10 C"` **Heres the weirdest part:** After refresh, it said `["classes"]=> &array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "11 A" [1]=> string(4) "10 C" }` and on another refresh, it said `["classes"]=> &array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Array" }`

**This only happens on my web host though, not on my local server. And, only on this page**

I have no idea what's causing this, or how to fix it

Comment: you may edit the session somewhere, try to find it. Or it will be strange behavior

Comment: It is strange behaviour... like i said, i haven't changed the session variable at all. plus, it works perfectly well on my local server

Comment: can you pls post complete code? Also, which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @SatishGadhave Here's the complete code: [link](http://justpaste.it/33av), and php version: 5.2.42

Comment: Weird too that "&" should appear in your var_dump(). This suggests you have references to data, rather than the data itself. I don't know what the implications of this would be for the session, but it may explain why only one server behaves itself. I had a quick look through your code, and it seems fine.

Comment: @user936401 Exactly, I still can't figure this out! And i dont see any reason as to why a reference should break the code, since im just reading data from the session.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have [`register_globals`](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) turned on so `$classes` gets mixed with `$_SESSION['classes']` at some point.

You should turn them off. [(Here's why.)](http://php.net/manual/pl/security.globals.php)

Or, if turning them off is not possible due to whatever reason, change variable names.

Comment: If turning them off is not possible, I'd probably start looking for a new host (if indeed this is the case)

Comment: Well I think changing variable name solved the trick. I also changed the script a bit. Look at my answer. Got it from a Wizpert at https://wizpert.com/ :D

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Here's my new code:

```
<?php
    $classesBeingTaught[] = explode(",", $_SESSION['classes']);
    foreach ($classesBeingTaught[0] as $classBeingTaught) {
        echo "<option>".$classBeingTaught."</option>";
    }
?>
```